# UITableView weird crash on row deletion

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitableview, uikit, crash

I have an UITableView whose rows can be deleted. this table view has a search bar at the top. the problem is: if search was used, application crashes when I try to delete any row from the table view. there is no information in the debugger console. all I have is function stack from the debugger:

[image]

Any ideas what it can be?

UPDATE 1: crash happens only if I return UISearchBar is a header view for UITableView's section.

UPDATE 2: contacts Apple DTS and they confirmed this is an SDK bug.

Comment: "The application crashes" isn't a very useful thing to say about the problem. I've never once had the application crash without the console saying SOMETHING helpful, and I frankly don't believe that's happening here, either. Could be you don't know what to look at, though.

Comment: console says NOTHING. not even 'bad memory access' or anything similar, neither an internal inconsistency exception message.

Comment: Could it be that, when deleting the row from the search results, the indexPath of the deleted cell doesn't match the indexPath of your actual data in your WAChatStorage object and you are deleting the wrong data from storage?

Comment: first, I use only one section, therefore index of deleted object within data model doesn't matter. second, look at the update to my question - I think something wrong happens when I set searchBar as a section header. when I set it as UITableView's tableHeaderView everything works fine

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what cause your problems but usually for me, I remove the object from the Data Source (usually, the NSArray that fills your table) and call `[tableView reloadData];`

Comment: this approach removes deleted cell immediately with no animation. I'd like to animate row deletion